# WPF - IsMouseOver Still True Even If Mouse Not Over

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

Simple question, why is it True while it should NOT be.
I'm talking XAML here, and controls property `IsMouseOver`.
This can be tested by creating a trigger like this (style example):

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFCACACB"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you leave the primary mouse button (Left Button - Right Handed) pressed while leaving the control (button), the control will have background color of `IsMouseOver` state until the button is released (Default state) or got back over the button (`IsPressed` state).

Why is it happening ? Is there any workaround ?

**Edit**
Finally found out, why it's happening. It seems like it uses the MouseLeave event to set the property to False and MouseLeave event won't fire until the mouse button is released (that's why **SledgeHammer** used MouseMove event instead). If you have just one button (any control) on the form/window then you can use the code from the accepted answer, but if you got a standalone control (user/custom control), like I do then you can't use it (MouseMove won't trigger if outside of it).

If anyone got better answer, usable on user/custom controls, then do what you should do...
*I really can't make it work - must deal with it :)*

Comment: Why do you want to change this?

Comment: @GlenThomas Trying to copy the design of Window Control Buttons of Win10, even Steam is doing it the same.

Comment: I have Windows 10 and all of the buttons that I've seen have the same effect; pressed styling remains until mouse is released.

Comment: Window Control Buttons = Minimize, Maximize/Restore, Close....

Comment: MouseMove will trigger outside the control, but you need to capture the mouse when the button is pressed and release the mouse capture when the mouse button is released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible in XAML only because the IsMouseOver property behaves in a different way that you expect (although its operating correctly). The workaround is simple... just add the following code and bind to IsMouseOverEx instead of IsMouseOver.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMouseOverExProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsMouseOverEx", typeof(bool),
        typeof(xxx), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

    public bool IsMouseOverEx
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(IsMouseOverExProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(IsMouseOverExProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private void xxx_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        IsMouseOverEx = false;
    }

    private void xxx_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point pt = e.GetPosition(this);

        if ((pt.X < 0.0) || (pt.Y < 0.0) || (pt.X >= ActualWidth) || (pt.Y >= ActualHeight))
            IsMouseOverEx = false;
        else
            IsMouseOverEx = true;
    }
```

Comment: Looking good! I'm gonna edit it a bit, because I'm creating User Control that got the button inside it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As the mouse is captured when you click, you can use MultiTrigger to tell the control to change it's background only when the mouse is over, but not captured.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
            <Condition Property="IsMouseCaptured" Value="False"/>
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE5E5E5"/>
    </MultiTrigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFCACACB"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Of course, when the mouse is clicked the background change is lost, but IsPressed trigger changes it to a different color anyway. I didn't spend too much time playing with this, so there might be some unwanted side effects, but it seems to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Working as designed. Some controls (like buttons) capture the mouse when you click. So think of a button as having the following states:

```
1) normal
2) hot
3) hot pressed
4) non-hot pressed (this is the state you are complaining about)
```

Some controls will visually indicate that 4th state when the control is pressed, but the mouse isn't over it (but the mouse is captured).

You'll also notice that if you pressed and hold the mouse button, no other controls will react to the mouse over because that button has captured the mouse.

Sometimes, I need to do what you are after, so I just add a IsMouseOverEx DP to the control and make sure its within the bounds of the control while ignoring the mouse capture.

Comment: Can you give me an example code ? The best would be to use XAML-only approach (if possible), if not then example of use XAML + C#/VB.net.